# R: apply as.list to data frame converts numeric to character

Tags: r, list, dataframe, apply

When trying to convert data frame to a list resembling a nested dictionary I tried using a following command:

```
 df = data.frame(col1 = c('a', 'b'), col2 = c(1, 2))
 df[,1] = as.character(df[,1])

 ls1 = apply(df, 1, as.list)
 print(ls1)
```

However, the values of col2 in ls1 now seem to be converted to character:

```
 class(ls1[[2]]$col2)
 # [1] "character"
```

This workaround works, but I am curious if somebody knows, why the result is not the same as in previous code?

```
 ls2 = as.list(df[1,])
 for(i in 2:nrow(df)){
   ls2 = list(ls2, as.list(df[i,]))
 }
 print(ls2)

 class(ls1[[2]]$col2)
 # [1] "numeric"
```

Comment: It is better not to use `apply` as it converts to `matrix` first.  Try `split(df, seq_len(nrow(df)))`

Comment: @IceCreamToucan I am not sure I know what you meant, the thole gymnastics was to get the `df` in a JSON form like: `{"list":[{"col1":"a","col2":1},{"col1":"b","col2":2}]}` somehow... (sorry for being to short in explaining the problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `apply`, which converts the data to `matrix` and `matrix` can have only single class, use `split`

```
lst1 <- unname(split(df, seq_len(nrow(df))))
```

If we need a `JSON` output, the dataset can be directly converted to `JSON` with `toJSON`

```
jsonlite::toJSON(df)
#[{"col1":"a","col2":1},{"col1":"b","col2":2}]
```

Based on the conversation with OP, dataset is passed as a named `list` that needs to be converted to JSON format

```
toJSON(list(listName = df))
#{"listName":[{"col1":"a","col2":1},{"col1":"b","col2":2}]}
```

Comment: I have tried using split before, but the problem was that I was unable to remove row names - for example to convert to JSON (for some reason I cannot write in code mode sorry):

ls3 = split(df, seq_len(nrow(df)))

Comment: @MatijaCerne  You can change `unname(split(df, seq_len(nrow(df))))`

Comment: @MatijaCerne  What is your expected output

Comment: `[{"col1":"a","col2":1},{"col1":"b","col2":2}]` would be perfect

Comment: ``[[{"col1":"a","col2":1}],[{"col1":"b","col2":2}]]`` is what comes from `unname(split(...))`

Comment: @MatijaCerne  For this, you don't need any split. as the key/value pairs would be the column names, value of columns.  Can you check my update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190638/discussion-between-matija-cerne-and-akrun).

Comment: @MatijaCerne  Isn't that the expected output you showed int the comments by using `jsonlite::toJSON(df)`

Comment: yes, it is... but I was a bit short on the desired output, using toJSON directly on data.frame was my first try, but my desired output is something like: `{"listName":[{"col1":"a","col2":1},{"col1":"b","col2":2}]}` and I couldnt get it in this form

Comment: @MatijaCerne Where does `list` comes in the example.  I think you can have a different structure

Comment: See edit please, I updated 'list' to 'listName' to clarify... basically I'm trying to pass df to a site using df first as JSON in authentication signature and then posting same data as a list in message body (I use httr)

Comment: @MatijaCerne  I don't see any new edits in your post  Are you passing objects as `list(df)`

Comment: @MatijaCerne  It is better you provide the `dput` of the example that created the "listName"

Comment: `{"listName":[{"col1":"a","col2":1},{"col1":"b","col2":2}]}` in JSON class would be my desired output, and list is desired for me because I have to use it in order for a POST function to work

Comment: @MatijaCerne  I just wanted the input along with the output.